# How to TCP server serves forever?

Tags: python, network-programming

Hello everyone!

I'm new to python networking programming.

My development environments are as below.

- Windows 7
- Python 3.4

I am studying with "Python Network Programming Cookbook". In this book, there's an example of **ThreadingMixIn** socket server application.

This book's code is written in Python 2.7. So I've modified for python 3.4.
The code is...

```
# coding: utf-8

import socket
import threading
import socketserver

SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT = 0  # tells the kernel to pick up a port dynamically
BUF_SIZE = 1024


def client(ip, port, message):
    """ A client to test threading mixin server"""
    # Connect to the server
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip, port))
    try:
        message = bytes(message, encoding="utf-8")
        sock.sendall(message)
        response = sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
        print("Client received: {0}".format(response))
    finally:
        sock.close()


class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """ An example of threaded TCP request handler """
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        current_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = "{0}: {0}".format(current_thread.name, data)
        response = bytes(response, encoding="utf-8")
        self.request.sendall(response)


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    """Nothing to add here, inherited everything necessary from parents"""
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run server
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT),
    ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address # retrieve ip address

    # Start a thread with the server -- one thread per request
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)

    # Exit the server thread when the main thread exits
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("Server loop running on thread: {0}".format(server_thread))

    # Run clients
    client(ip, port, "Hello from client 1")
    client(ip, port, "Hello from client 2")
    client(ip, port, "Hello from client 3")
```

This code works perfect. Every client's request processed by new thread. And when the client's request is over, program ends.

**I want to make server serves forever.** So when the additional client's request has come, server send its response to that client.

What should I do?

Thank you for reading my question.

P.S: Oh, one more. I always write say hello in top of my post of stack overflow.  In preview it shows normally. But when the post has saved, first line always gone. Please anyone help me XD

Comment: I don't have python3 installed, but I don't see anything that could cause the server to stop. Are you sure the program exits? Just because you're seeing the python input prompt `>>>` doesn't mean the program has stopped running. Try adding `server_thread.join()` at the bottom. EDIT: I just realized you're making the server thread a daemon. Don't do that. It says right there "**Exit the server thread when the main thread exits**".

Comment: @Rawing, I use PyCharm as python IDE. When that code runs, it shows to me this message. "Process finished with exit code 0". And I added server_thread.join() as you suggested, It works! It serves forever!

Comment: @Rawing, Oh my god! Rawing you're right!! I just commented the "server_thread.daemon = True" and server served forever without "server_thread.join()" Thank you Rawing. You saved my whole day! XD

Comment: @Rawing, I want to adopt your answer. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program exits because your server thread is a daemon:

```
# Exit the server thread when the main thread exits
server_thread.daemon = True
```

You can either remove that line or add `server_thread.join()` at the bottom of the code to prevent the main thread from exiting early.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run on an infinite loop and on each loop wait for some data to come from client. This way the connection will be kept alive.

Same infinite loop for the server to accept more clients.

However, you will have to somehow detect when a client closes the connection with the server because in most times the server won't be notified.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question. You've pointed out important part of network programming I thought.